# Download link to exact terminal icon?

Tags: user-interface, terminal, icons

Does anyone link to download the exact terminal icon from terminal?

Comment: http://images.google.com/images?q=terminal%20filetype%3Apng

Comment: which terminal do you mean, Kevin?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the Mac OS X app Terminal, then you can [extract the icon image directly](http://mactoids.com/how-to-copy-mac-application-icons/).